# Template - class that uses int, short or float when necessary

Tags: c++

I want to write a class that manages euclidean vector and that store its initial point using short, int, long or float. I thought to create a template like this:

```
    template<class unit> class EVector
{
private:
    unit x;
    unit y;
public:
    EVector();
    setX();
    setY();
};
```

So user creates an EVector choosing the suitable primitive type. But how can I implement the operation between different classes, e.g.

```
EVector<int> a;
EVector<float> b;

EVector<double> c;

c = a + b;
```

operator= will copy the coordinates,  operator+ adds them.

Comment: This question seems to tread on similar ground http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629829/ambiguous-overload-on-template-operators It might be of use to you.

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For addition, you can use my [`promote`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426330/uses-of-a-c-arithmetic-promotion-header/2450157#2450157) implementation:

```
template<typename A, typename B> 
EVector<typename promote<A, B>::type>
operator +(EVector<A> const& a, EVector<B> const& b) {
  EVector<typename promote<A, B>::type> ev;
  ev.setX(a.getX() + b.getX());
  ev.setY(a.getY() + b.getY());
  return ev;
}
```

For types `double` and `int`, it will yield `double` for example.

Comment: So this solution won't take into account all conversions, only promotions. Not sure if this is what the OP wants. I like the promote implementation, though, so, here's +1 from me ;)

Comment: @Armen all conversions that `?:` does, which comes down to all conversions if I'm not mistaken :) For example `char*` and `std::string` will work too, even though that's not a promotion of any kind. The name `promote` could perhaps be renamed. Thanks for your +1 :)

Comment: If it'll work for all conversions, what's the need of such scary code when a simple templated copy-constructor and copy-assignment would do?

Comment: @Armen I would be eager to know how you would write `operator+` with templated constructors :)

Comment: I'd just write a simple operator + and one of the operands would get converted to the other one via the constructor.

Comment: @Armen which one will be converted to which other one? Should `a + b` yield `1` if `a` is `int 1` and `b` is `float 0.3`, because you always convert to the left operand?

Comment: @Johannes It's hard for me to fully understand your implementation, but I think this is the right solution. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You want to enable assignment(and copy-construction) from `EVector<U>` to `EVector<T>` when `U`is convertible to `T`

```
template<class T>
class EVector
{
   template<class U>
   EVector(EVector<U> const & rhs)
           :x(rhs.x), y(rhs.y)
   {
   }
   ...
}
```

Note that even if you have provided this templated copy-constructor, the compiler will generate a copy-constructor for you( when `T` is same as `U`). In this case you're fine with that default implementation - it does exactly what you need. But otherwise you'd have to explicitly define the nontemplated constructor(and copy-assignment) as well.

Comment: "Note that once you have provided this templated copy-constructor, you'll have to explicitly provide a nontemplated one as well", this is not true :)

Comment: @Johannes: Oh, OK, I got it... I'll think how to edit now... :)

Comment: I like it more but I'm not sure what you mean by "But otherwise". In what cases would an explicitly defined nontemplated copy constructor be needed? I can't understand.

Comment: @Johannes: When you're not happy with the compiler generated copy constructor. My point is that providing a templated "copy-"constructor will not prevent the compiler from generating a real copy-constructor - and that badly generated one will be called when you initialize `EVector<T>` from `EVector<T>` - not the instantiation of the template with `U = T`